# Understanding the number of partitions created by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How many partitions will pyspark-sql create while reading a .csv?

My understanding of this is that
 `number of partitions = math.ceil(file_size/spark.conf.get('spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes'))`

On my machine:

```
spark.conf.get('spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes')
output: 
'134217728b' #128MBs
```

However, I am not observing this behaviour. I create a file that is taking up 96 MB on disk. I run spark in local mode. I have an 8 core laptop. I think it should have read in 1 partition. However, the file is getting read in 8 partitions. Below is the codebase I have used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
#creating a small DataFrame. This will occupy 96 MBs on disk
pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(10000000),'b':np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d'],size=(10000000,),p=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25])}).to_csv('df_s.csv',index=None)
sd=spark.read.csv('df_s.csv',schema="id int, b string")
sd.rdd.getNumPartitions()
output: 8
```

Can you please help me understand why am I seeing 8 partitions irrespective of the file size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The actual formula is actually a bit more complicated than that. Check the below calculation. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/DataSourceScanExec.scala#L607-L653).

**This is your configuration and your file**

| Spark Configuration | Value | Default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes | 128M | 128M |
| spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes | 4M | 4M |
| spark.executor.instances | 1 | local |
| spark.executor.cores | 8 | your cores |
| spark.default.parallelism | 8 | =spark.executor.instances * spark.executor.cores |
| data files size | 64M |  |
| data files count | 1 |  |

**This is the actual formula**

|  | Formula | Bytes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DefaultMaxSplitBytes | = spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes | 134,217,728 |
| OpenCostInBytes | = spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes | 4,194,304 |
| DefaultParallelism | = spark.default.parallelism | 8 |
| TotalBytes | = DataBytes + (# files * OpenCostInBytes) | 71,303,168 |
| BytesPerCore | = TotalBytes / DefaultParallelism | 8,912,896 |
| MaxSplitBytes | = MIN(DefaultMaxSplitBytes, MAX(OpenCostInBytes, BytesPerCore)) | 8,912,896 |
| Estimated number of partition | = TotalBytes / MaxSplitBytes | **8** |